# How to check datasource in JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, jmx

I have a datasource, how to check if its ok? maybe somehow using jmx-console?

Comment: Which JBoss version are you using?

Comment: jboss-4.2.1.GA, but if its possible in another I can switch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want just check if data source is installed and some statistic information about it you can read that bean: `jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=ManagedConnectionPool`.

You can find such bean for each data source, just change `DefaultDS` with the data source name.

Answer (score 4):

With JBoss 7, you can use the jboss-admin command line tool to test the datasource. Run this line in jboss-admin (after adjusting the JNDI name of the datasource, and example assuming that it is an XA datasource):

/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=java\:jboss/datasources/XAOracleDS:test-connection-in-pool

More details can be found here: http://www.javalinux.it/wordpress/2011/07/14/how-to-create-an-manage-datasources-in-as7/

Answer (score 1):

The above did not work for me, but this worked-

Run this line in jboss-cli:

/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=jdbc\/XAOracleDS:test-connection-in-pool

Answer (score 1):

Using Jboss CLI, a datasource (e.g. MyDS) can be targeted directly:

> /subsystem=datasources/data-source=MyDS:test-connection-in-pool