# What is the Max Pool Connection size if no Max Pool Connection is set in -ds.xml?

Tags: jboss

Does anyone know what the default value is of the max pool size within the -ds.xml file?  As you can see below we only have minimum set to 0 with no entry for maxium.  I'm worried the vendor who configured this was thinking no maximum entry means unlimited.  Im wondering if no entry takes the default value Jboss assigns. I'm not sure what that value is.

Reason i'm concerned is because I'm getting this error:

Njavax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Error obtaining connection: org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] ); - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] ));

My -ds.xml file

```
datasources>
<local-tx-datasource>
<jndi-name>SabaSite</jndi-name>
<connection-url>saba:jdbc:JSQLConnect://********/database=######/asciiStringParameters=false</connection-url>
<driver-class>com.saba.mssql.SabaJNETMSSQLDatabaseDriver</driver-class>
<min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
<exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
</local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Thanks,

Justin

Answer (score 1):

You can check actual datasource properties yourself with help of [JMX Console](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JMXConsole).

See [How to check datasource in JBoss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212284/how-to-check-datasource-in-jboss)